# Replacing backslash in haskell

Tags: haskell, escaping, backslash

Hi I am trying to remove the substring `"\r"` by replacing it with an empty string in the following function:

```
clean :: String -> String
clean ('\\':'r':xs) = clean xs
clean (x:xs) = x : clean xs
clean "" = ""
```

But when I run it on a test input:

```
main = do
    print (clean "test line\r\nnew test")
```

it doesn't work and just outputs the same string as the input string. Now the weird thing is that if I replace the backslashes with any other character, for example `':'` it works just fine:

```
clean :: String -> String
clean (':':'r':xs) = clean xs
clean (x:xs) = x : clean xs
clean "" = ""

main = do
    print (clean "test line:r\nnew test")
```

Which outputs `"test line\nnew test"` as intended. I suspect that I'm not escaping the double backslash correctly. For example the code:

```
main = do
    print '\\'
```

outputs `'\\'` instead of `'\'`, but from what I've read this *should* be the proper way to escape it. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, what am I missing?

Comment: `print string` will _escape_ and then output `string`. It's equivalent to `putStrLn (show string)`, where `show` does the escaping. Use `putStrLn string` to output the string as-is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\r` is one character. It works when you handle it that way:

```
clean :: String -> String
clean ('\r':xs) = clean xs
clean (x:xs) = x : clean xs
clean "" = ""
```

The backslash only needs to be escaped when you want to put an actual `\` into the String literal.

Answer (score 3):

`"\r"` is a string with *one* character, the backslash is used to represent a [*carriage return*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), just like the double quotes (`"…"`) are not part of the *content* of the string either.

You can filter out a carriage return with:

```
clean :: String -> String
clean = filter ('\r' /=)
```